# Class attributes out of scope after added to list

Tags: python, oop, scope

I'm building a class that optimizes SKLearn's GBoost classifier by iterating over the hyper-parameters and checking scores. My class has attributes that relate to each parameter used by the classifier, all defined in `self.__init__`. The method that changes the params stores them in a list, then loops over the list like so:

```
param_list = [self.param1, self.param2]
for param in param_list:
    param += 1 #adjust param and check score
```

Unfortunately, adding the attributes to a list is taking them out of scope, or for another reason they are not being updated.

Comment: What do you mean they're "functioning improperly". Please provide a [mre].

Comment: You appear to be trying to modify immutable values.

Comment: `self.param1 += 1` would work because it translates to something like `setattr(self, 'param', self.param+1)`. `param += 1` is equivalent to `param = param + 1`, which does nothing to `self.param1` itself.

Comment: `for p in ('param1', 'param2'): setattr(self, p, getattr(self, p) + 1)`.

Comment: Indexing into param list with (for i in range(len(param_list)): also does not seem to work!

Comment: That's it, @ekhumoro! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks chepner and ekhumoro for the perfect solution:

```
param_list = ['param1', 'param2']
for param in param_list:
    setattr(self, param, getattr(self, param) + 1)
```

By using setattr, the class attribute is changes instead of the local variable.